# Matplotlib - plt.show() on chart object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a really simple example here. I'm making a plot from an ax object returned from a function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]

def make_plot():

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title('test bar chart')

    return ax


chart = make_plot()
chart.bar(x, y)

plt.show()               #why does this show the chart?
```

My question is about plt.show() at the end. Obviously, this shows the output of the chart. But why?  To me it does not seem like plt.show() is tied to anything. I have my `chart` object, which contains my chart with all its parameters and whatnot. But how does plt.show() know to interact with this?  It would seem more intuitive to have something like `chart.show()`, as `chart` is the class instance.

Comment: First sentence of the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! `chart` is an Axes created when you call `plt.subplots()`. Pyplot is what's called a "stateful" API. When you make calls to plt.* functions, it changes the internal state of pyplot and that can affect future calls. When you call `plt.subplots()`, it knows that there is a newly created Figure with newly created subplot Axes inside it.

Similarly, if you call `plt.plot()`, it has a stored record of what the most recent axes are, and plots the data on that plot.

[Take a look at the pyplot sourcecode](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L766) and you can see how it has a global `manager` variable that it uses to store the current plot, and updates that `manager` when you create a plot.

Additionally, there is `Figure.show()`. [If you want to work around pyplot, it looks something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810109/1275942)